# Как передать заголовок авторизации с одним токеном

Tags: python, requests, авторизация

Пытаюсь подключится к роутеру, но не понимаю как авторизоваться с одним токином.
подскажите как еще можно реализовать подключение с 1 ключем ведь блока Form Data нету?
Роутер можно потыкать [здесь](https://emulator.tp-link.com/Emulator_TL-WR840NV6(RU)/index.htm).

```
import requests


router_ip='http://192.168.0.1'
auth_token='Authorization=Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='

def login():
    r = requests.get(router_ip+'/userRpm/LoginRpm.htm?Save=Save',
                     headers={'Referer': router_ip+'/', 'Cookie': auth_token})
    if r.status_code == 200:
        x = 1
        while x < 3:
            try:
                session_id = r.text[r.text.index(router_ip)+len(router_ip)+1:r.text.index('userRpm')-1]
                return session_id
                break
            except ValueError:
                return 'Login error'
            x += 1
    else:
        return 'IP unreachable'
```

Comment: Может использовать `headers = {"Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="}` вместо *Cookie*?

Comment: Сейчас проверил в моем роутере, там тоже нет `Form Data`, но есть вкладка *payload*, в ней и находятся нужные данные. Проверял в Google Chrome

Comment: пробовал, не работает
headers = {"Authorization": "Basic%20YWRtaW46YWRtaW4%3D"} и так тоже

Comment: %20-- пробел
%3D-- равно